# How do i know if Yolov8 training working correctly? i don't know if cuda is working correctly or using cudnn

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo

I'm new at programming and for a homework i was trying to use yolov8. It is using well at cpu but takes years. Using gpu is harder than i think. I was hoping just downloading a library and changing the code a little would be enough. I am not sure this is working right.

i have cuda 12.1 and nightly version of pytorch(if i understand right it should have cudnn inside). Im using pycharm.

what i am asking is: is yolo working correctly and using the GPU?

The code i am using is:

````
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  

if __name__ == '__main__':
results = model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=100, device="0")  ```

The output i am getting is same thing again and again and after some time(around 30 seconds) epoch 1 starts training. This repeats every epoch. I search a lot but everyone seems to be using google collab


`

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs

Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.23  Python-3.9.13 torch-2.3.0.dev20231231+cu121 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, 6144MiB)
yolo\engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=None, data=config.yaml, epochs=100, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, cache=False, device=0, workers=8, project=None, name=None, exist_ok=False, pretrained=False, optimizer=SGD, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, image_weights=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, show=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, vid_stride=1, line_thickness=3, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, boxes=True, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, fl_gamma=0.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, cfg=None, v5loader=False, save_dir=runs\detect\train28
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=2

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    751702  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [2, [64, 128, 256]]           
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3011238 parameters, 3011222 gradients, 8.2 GFLOPs

optimizer: SGD(lr=0.01) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias
train: Scanning C:\Users\yagiz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\datasets\solar\train\labels.cache... 858 images, 9 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 858/858 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
val: Scanning C:\Users\yagiz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\datasets\solar\valid\labels.cache... 39 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 8 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs\detect\train28
Starting training for 100 epochs...

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs


                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs


                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs


                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs


                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs


                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs



`
This goes on for a while couldnt paste all of it because of character limit
````

Comment: torch-2.3.0.dev20231231+cu121 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, 6144MiB) seems to indicate that it probably is. Is it training faster than on your CPU?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, it seems like yolo is training on GPU: device=0 [means](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/train/#key-features-of-train-mode) this, otherwise, it would be device=cpu. But there are some unusual patterns: model=None (must be model=yolov8n.yaml) in the received arguments and multiple outputs of not-overrode model summary (for nc=80). Try to rewrite the code without 'if ' statement or define the model inside it.